# .setValue() Not Consistently Working for Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling with a piece of script I wrote in a Google Sheet. The purpose of the script is to monitor the input value (from the keyboard) for a given cell and validate that the input follows a data entry standard.

For example, all input values must follow the standard `XX-XX-X`. As an example, `A5-03-1` is acceptable, whereas `B555-01-1` is not. (The first component is 4 digits instead of 2.) When the input value does not follow the standard, I use a `.setValue()` command to erase the entry...

```
Sheet.getRange(active cell).setValue("");
```

The `.setValue()` is also followed by a message box:

```
Browser.msgBox("Expecting format ''XX-XX-X''. \\n Please re-enter data.");
```

The logical statements for this code are working fine. What isn't working fine is `.setValue()`. Sometimes it erases the entry as desired, other times the invalid entry remains. However, the message box **always** shows appropriately. Both activities are in the same logical test.

Furthermore, I have granted Authorization to the script containing `setValue()`. But I get daily e-mails of errors for this sheet with errors along the line of "Authorization is required to perform that action."

Lastly--I have other uses inputting data into this sheet. All users have granted access to the script.

Comment: Fixed your tags - please don't tag with irrelevant terms

Comment: Thanks Tim! I didn't mean to use an irrelevant term... I know Excel VBA is an entirely different domain from Google Sheets Script. I used the tag on the basis that both are Spreadsheets... My bad!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the `setValue()` function isn't working, but instead, try using `clear()` after you use `getRange()`.

Comment: I have an update! The function clear() was also working sporadically. However, when I commented out the script to produce the message box, both setValue() and clear() started working consistently.

Is there some kind of interaction between between the Browser.msgBox() and setValue() functions???

Comment: I'm not familiar with Browser.msgBox() so I can't give you a definitive answer, but it doesn't seem like they would be related.  You could try to use the flush() function in between those two functions.  Maybe that would solve the issue??

Comment: Thanks Calvin, I added "SpreadsheetApp.flush();" after the .setValue action and before Browser.msgBox();

After this change, the .setValue() is always working but the msgBox is sporadic! Sometimes it comes up and other times it does not. Very strange.