# 'setValue' errs, but only sometimes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, runtime-error, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to fetch stock prices from the web and save them automatically every five minutes or so. I've succeeded with the importXML() and the Google Sheets triggers but I do encounter ERRORS quite often. The problems seem to rise when saving the values from the imported cells to a new column at the end of the spreadsheet. Sometimes it all works fine, but sometimes some cells get an error and sometimes I get ERROR in all the cells.

This is the Google script I'm using:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var queryString = Math.random();
  for (var i=2; i <= 14; i++) {
    var cell = '=IMPORTXML("' + 'http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/ppaper.php?paper=' + sheet.getRange('B' + i + '').getValue() + '.ST&' + queryString + '","'  + sheet.getRange('A' + i + '').getValue() +  '")';
    sheet.getRange('C' + i + '').setValue(cell);
  }
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();
  var nextColumn = numColumns + 1;
  sheet.getRange(1, nextColumn).setValue(new Date());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sheet.getRange(2, numColumns + 1, 13, 1).setValues(sheet.getRange(2, 4, 13, 1).getValues());
}
```

And here is the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LYSqbvM-PWmvzQMFNL4QThcAkdhGU7CGq6DBp2SLyWc/edit?usp=sharing).

In [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680988/setvalue-not-consistently-working-for-google-sheets-script) I found out that adding a `Browser.msgBox("hey!")` and a `clear()` could help. But it still gives me errors trying it out unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please verify on the script, if there was any error while executing the trigger? You can check under Script Editor > View > Execution Transcript.

Comment: The xml might be containing wrong values, or you might also be hitting the appscript quotas when executing the trigger.

Comment: Nope, there is no errors when looking at the Execution Transcript.
I have been getting a few emails when google shut of some of the scripts I've tried for a short while, because of to much data prosessing. But then it continues to collect data.
I'm pretty sure that the errors is not occuring when fetching the data with importXML, since I can seee all the values getting pulled in, in column C. It's when copying the value of that cell with setValue something must go wrong...